# Why when sending a post request to another service, the data is transmitted incorrectly?

Tags: python, json, post

So, what's going on and what I mean. I have this code here.

```
def predict_nn(self, dataframe):
    model_predict_heating_time = model.predict(pd.json_normalize(dataframe))
    create_post(model_predict_heating_time[0][0])
```

```
def create_post(self, heating_time):
    url = "https://mihailmaximov.ru/projects/json/json.php"
    data = {"time": str(heating_time)}
    response = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(data))
```

The model receives a file in the form of json, I transform it into pd.DataFrame and give it to another function that generates json and sends it to the server, for the test I took this `https://mihailmaximov.ru/projects/json/json.php`.

If I convert `heating_time` to a string in the `create_post` method, when everything is ok and something like.

```
def predict_nn(self, dataframe):
    model_predict_heating_time = model.predict(pd.json_normalize(dataframe))
    model_predict_heating_time = str(model_predict_heating_time[0][0])
    create_post(model_predict_heating_time)
```

```
def create_post(self, heating_time):
    url = "https://mihailmaximov.ru/projects/json/json.php"
    data = {"time": heating_time}
    response = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(data))
```

```
[
  "{\"time\": \"-10007662.0\"}"
],
```

But if I transform `model_predict_heating_time` to str in the `predict_nn` method.

It will send something like this to json:

```
[
  "{\"time\": \"2\"}"
],
```

At this time , the value from the model itself will be in the form of 235436.0
That is, for some reason, only the first element from `heating_time` is sent to the site.

What can this be related to? Could you explain it to me? Maybe this is a problem on the part of the site, but I'm not sure.

If you give a pre-converted string to `create_post`, but already one element is sent on the site.
Don't pay attention to the output of the model.